# Query to select the sum of a column between two dates where some condition is true

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, between

```
        ResultSet rs1 = state.executeQuery("select sum(bill_total) as bill_total"
                      + " from t_report where date between ? and ? AND  mode_of_payment='Cash' ");
        PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst1.setString(1, date1.getText());
        pst1.setString(2, date2.getText());
        while(rs1.next()){
        cash_label.setText(rs1.getString("bill_total"));
        }
```

I tried this Query but it's not working. I get error : Incorrect syntax near '?'
Out of the the two conditions only the payment method condition is working an the date condition is not working.

Comment: Any error or result?

Comment: error is  "incorrect syntax near '?' "

Comment: Do you run this query exactly as at the question?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get no result or a wrong one? Have you provided the actual parameters for the `?`s in the `sqlsrv_prepare` function?

Comment: Can you replace ? with {0} and {1} respectively.

Comment: what do you mean ? @osmanraifgunes

Comment: i get result but instead of getting the sum only between the two specified dates i get the sum of every record which was payed by cash. that means only the clause with the cash condition is working @cars10

Comment: change the name of column date to something else and try. it is a reserve work.

Comment: As @suneel just correctly pointed out: date is a reserved word. Try and enclose the column name in square brackets like `[date]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(bill_total) AS bill_total FROM t_report WHERE (date BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('01/01/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') ) AND  (mode_of_payment='Cash')
```

Comment: i just added the paranthesis to my query because i need to take the date dynamically but it still gave the same error: incorrect syntax near '?' @user7414515

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
pst1.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime()));
pst1.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime()));
```

Comment: I am using java with netbeans.

Comment: Edited from c# to java @Mohit

Comment: date1 and date2 are text fields from which the date is being retrieved . I can't use getTime() with date1 and date2.

Comment: Tried this : new java.sql.Date(date2.getText()) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this
Here is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE bill_total2(bill_total integer,mode_of_payment string,date1 datetime);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO bill_total2 VALUES(1,'cash','12-12-2016 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO bill_total2 VALUES(2,'cash','12-12-2016 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO bill_total2 VALUES(3,'cash','12-12-2016 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO bill_total2 VALUES(4,'cash','12-12-2016 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO bill_total2 VALUES(5,'cash','12-12-2016 00:00:00');
```

and my query is

```
SELECT sum(bill_total) FROM bill_total2 
WHERE date1 BETWEEN '12-12-2016 00:00:00' AND '12-12-2016 00:00:00'
AND mode_of_payment='cash';
```

this is working fine for me.

Comment: So why do you think it is not working in my code . i can't directly put the date like you did as it is being retrieved from the front end.

Comment: as i said in comment change the name of column date its a reserve word. I inserted that data for testing purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the query before setting the parameters! Please try this:

```
String sql = "select sum(bill_total) as bill_total"
          + " from t_report where date between ? and ? AND  mode_of_payment='Cash' ");
PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst1.setString(1, date1.getText());
pst1.setString(2, date2.getText());
ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next()){
    cash_label.setText(rs1.getString("bill_total"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro . It was a stupid mistake. The query is running fine now.